# Using reserved name for a variable

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-esp8266, arduino-c++

1. problem is `int min` redeclared as a different kind of symbol;
2. Try to check the code and change the whole number, but I have the same problem, regardless of whether I change it to 0 1 2 3 4. (Sorry, I'm not good at English and just started to learn coding from education through Google and YouTube.)
3. This is my code:

   ```
   int int_count;
   int sec=0;
   int min=1;


   int flag_One_Time_Send_Old = 100;
   void timer0_ISR(void)                  // the RTCC (timer0) overflows (255->0). 
   if(--int_count==0)            // per second.
     sec++;
     int_count=INTS_PER_SECOND;
     if (sec==60)
    {
        min++;
        sec=0;
       Serial.print("min: ");
       Serial.println(min);
     }
       Serial.print("sec: ");
   Serial.println(sec);
   ```

   }

Thank for help

Comment: don't use `min` as variable name. Aduino uses it as min() (macro) function

Comment: May I please write to me as a sample?

Comment: sample of what? you don't know how to rename a variable?

Comment: Beside from using the reserved keyword, I'd like to point out it is not a good practice to do `Serial.print()` within an ISR. Please read [Interrupts](https://www.gammon.com.au/interrupts) by Nick Gammon for better understanding on how to write ISR.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works for you. `min` has been renamed as `minute` as `min` is used as `min()` macro function by Arduino.

```
int int_count; int sec=0; int minute=1;  //min renamed as minute

int flag_One_Time_Send_Old = 100;
void timer0_ISR(void)                  // the RTCC (timer0) overflows (255->0). 
if(--int_count==0)            // per second.
  sec++;
  int_count=INTS_PER_SECOND;
  if (sec==60)
 {
     minute++;
     sec=0;
    Serial.print("minutes: ");
    Serial.println(minute);
  }
    Serial.print("sec: ");
Serial.println(sec);
}
```

Comment: I think it's more like `minutes` in the TIME/RTC context. But it's definitely the worst macro name possible...

Comment: @KIIV I have renamed the variable again. I hope this one is useful to you.

Comment: Although this addressed OP's problem of using reserved key word. However, this is building upon a bad practise for ISR. Within the ISR, all interrupts was disabled, and therefore it should be kept as short as possible and never do any I/O operation (which is long and slow process), this including `Serial.print()`. Please read on how to using [Interrupt](https://www.gammon.com.au/interrupts) by Nick Gammon for better understanding of writing ISR.